# Static метод и static поле класса.

Tags: c++

Доброго времени суток. Предположим, есть класс:

```
class Set{
  public:
    Set(...){...}//конструктор
    ~Set();      //деструктор
    static get_num(){...}; // функция связана с использованием поля num;
  private:
    static int num;
};
```

Применение static к обычным функциям или переменным вне класса мне понятно, такой же самый смысл есть и при использовании модификатора static в классе, или это как-то связано  с вызовом функции в `main()`? Зачем так делать?

Буду благодарен за объяснение.

**Обновление**

Как я понял, поправьте, если ошибаюсь:

1. static поле класса создается с целью сделать его общим для все объектов класса, которые могут ее изменить при присвоении в main() и инициализируется вне класса, для того чтобы была выделенная память компилятором в глобальном участке.
2. static метод класса не может работать с НЕстатическими полями класса, так как такой метод получает неявно указатель this. (Уточнить, this присутствует из-за того, что функция является глобальной из-за спецификатора static? Или она всегда является глобальной и дело не в этом?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Статический означает, что он один и тот же на все экземпляры (объекты) класса. Неважно метод это или член класса.

Простой пример: все экземпляры автомашин класса Audi имеют одну и ту же марку "Ауди":

```
class AudiCars {
   static String model="Audi"; //название марки
   double mileage; //пробег
   String color; //цвет
}
```

Обычно статический метод в классе используется, когда необходимо что-то сделать такое, что относится к классу в целом, а не к конкретному объекту класса.

Ну а статический член класса - это свойство, относящееся к классу в целом, безотносительно к конкретному объекту класса.

**Обновление**

1. `main()` не имеет отношения к сабжу, кроме того простого факта, что он тоже `static`. Статическое поле класса может быть и `final` и `private`, так что он извне класса может быть и недоступен. В остальном ваши рассуждения верны.
2. Да, `static` метод класса не имеет доступа к нестатическим членам класса - у него нет `this`'а, что впрочем не отменяет возможности передачи ему в параметрах указателя на экземпляр класса, с которым ему можно работать.

Да и еще статический член/метод можно использовать и без создания экземпляра класса.

Answer (score 4):

Статических полей/методов не существует. Класс - это формальное описание объекта, или проще говоря тип. 
Переменная-член, или поле, или свойство - чего? Объекта данного типа, а не класса. Так вот, переменная-член входит в состав объекта, она является его частью, у каждого объекта она своя, и не существует без объекта. Именно поэтому переменную-член имеет смысл назвать свойством объекта.

Статическая переменная (а не поле, или свойство объекта) - это просто одна-единственная глобальная переменная, засунутая в неймспэйс класса. Она не входит в состав объекта, и существует независимо от количества объектов данного типа. Так что свойством объекта она быть не может.

Функция-член, или метод опять-таки объекта, а не класса. Предназначена для обработки объектов данного типа. Сама функция существует в единственном экземпляре, но чтобы она знала, с каким объектом нужно работать, ей неявным образом передается указатель на объект, он определяется как this, и он всегда указывает на объект, который вызвал метод. И метод нельзя вызвать при отсутствии объекта. Именно потому он - метод объекта.

Статическая функция, а не метод - это просто глобальная функция, засунутая в неймспэйс класса. Чтобы её вызвать не требуется объект, достаточно забраться в неймспэйс класса. И про объекты она ничего не знает, пока вы явным образом не дадите ей указатель или ссылку на объект, через которые она может забраться внутрь него. Но статические переменные она видит, в одном неймспэйсе всё-таки.

Answer (score 1):

Вот небольшой список, когда необходимо иметь static-метод или переменную:

1. При создании Синглтона Вы спрятали конструктор и деструктор в private-часть, и теперь клиентский код не может создать. Вопрос: Как тогда создавать? Можно путем static-метода static YourType& getInstance();
2. Вы пишите класс логер. С помощью метода getLogger() вы возвратили логер. Но при этом все логеры должны писать в один и тот же файл, как быть? Можно сделать static HANDLE hFile, и все объекты будут иметь доступ к этому приватному полю.

Answer (score 0):

Стоит заметить, что обращаться к видимым статическим членам-данным и статическим методам класса можно как через имя класса, так и через экземпляр класса. Можно догадаться - методы и статические методы, статические члены-данные располагаются в памяти в единичном экземпляре. Одна лишь разница, как заметил [[@Barmaley](/users/5648/barmaley)](/users/5648/barmaley) ♦ , вы не можете обратиться к статическим методам как к обычным из-за отсутствия неявной передачи в метод this.