# В чём разница между определением, объявлением, реализацией и инициализацией?

Tags: c++

В чём разница между определением, объявлением, реализацией и инициализацией?

Comment: Это всё разные слова. Неужели разница между значениями слов "реализация" и "инициализация" нуждается в объяснениях помимо того, что написано в толковом словаре?

Comment: @Igor просто везде по-разному пишут

Comment: Можете почитать [тут](http://cppstudio.com/post/2647/) первая ссылка в гугле :) или [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/cpp/declarations-and-definitions-cpp?view=msvc-160) вторая уже

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1140569 - связанный вопрос

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Если совсем кратко:

```
typedef int MyType; // объявление синонима типа

extern int value; // объявление переменной
int value;        // объявление + определение посредством неявной инициализации
int value2 = 0;   // объявление + определение посредством явной инициализации значением 0

int func();             // объявление функции (прототип функции)
int func(){ return 0; } // определение функции посредством реализации

class SomeClass; // объявление класса
class SomeClass  // определение класса
{ static int field; };    // объявление  static члена класса
int SomeClass::field = 0; // определение static члена класса посредством инициализации значением 0
```

---

**Явная и неявная инициализация переменных**

Если при определении переменной не происходит явного присвоения ей какого-либо значения (т.е. не происходит *явной инициализации*), то компилятор может проинициализировать её сам в соответствии со следующими правилами:

1. переменные со статическим временем существования (глобальные, в пространствах имен и статические) инициализируются нулем;
2. автоматические переменные не инициализируются (имеют случайное значение той области, которая была выделена под переменную на стеке);
3. динаммические переменные не инициализируются (имеют случайное значение той области памяти, которая была выделена под объект в куче).

Стоит заметить, что в большинстве реализаций в debug-версии под автоматические переменные область стека (stack) заполняется значениями `0xCCCCCCCC`, а область кучи (heap) заполняется `0xCDCDCDCD`, что может позволить при отладке выявлять использование неинициализированных переменных.

---

**Объявление и определение**

Стоит заметить, что объявлений может быть сколь угодно много, а определение лишь одно (за исключением `inline` функций, которые при этом не нарушают [ODR](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/418755/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-one-definition-rule)).

Comment: А если перед определением класса и функции не было их объявления, то это объявление + определение?

Comment: @Никита2003 Да, но вы ведь понимаете, что объявлений может быть сколь угодно много, а определение может быть лишь одно (за исключением `inline` функций, которые не нарушают при этом правила [ODR](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/418755/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-one-definition-rule))?

Comment: 1) `typedef` это не объявление нового типа, это синоним для уже существующего. По `typedef` нельзя сделать перегрузку функций, именно потому что это один и тот же тип, но с разными названиями. 2) Нет такого понятия как `явное/неявное определение`. 3) `поля` в `c++` бывают только битовые, то о чём Вы говорите, это `член`.

Comment: 1) [typedef](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0e5kx78b.aspx#Anchor_0) 5ый пункт
3) [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/b1b5y48f.aspx) (первое же предложение) и [wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0) (раздел про плюсы) так не считают, да и во многих [ответах на SO](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/373700/static-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B8-static-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0) постоянно проскальзывает данное понятие
2) поправил на явную/неявную инициализацию

Comment: 1) я не говорю, что это не `объявление` как таковое. Просто `своего` надо заменить на `синонима` и будет всё ок. 3) Посмотрите оригинал этого предложения. Поле - это `field`, а то что они перевели `member data` как `поле`, это не значит, что так правильно. Хотя так проще и короче, но формально - это не соответствует Стандарту. В общем, у меня просто pedantic-mode on. :)

Answer (score 2):

Объявление (*declaration*) - это сообщение о том, что объект такого типа с такми именем существует. Причём необязательно в текущей единице трансляции (*translation unit*).

Определение (*definition*) - это создание объекта (переменной, функции, класса, объекта класса, лямбды...). Причём объект - это не обязательно данные, это объект в самом широком смысле. Любое определение также является и объявлением.

Объявление функции также называется её прототипом (*function prototype*). А вообще в плюсах принято говорить о предварительном объявлении (*forward declaration*), особенно если речь идёт о классе.

Comment: Перенёс ответ в другой вопрос потому что тот был создан спамером с целью накрутки репутации. Возможно, ответ стоит немного дополнить.

Answer (score 1):

Хоть вопрос и старый, но я вставлю свои 5 копеек. [@StateItPrimitive](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/200756/stateitprimitive) утверждает, что объявлений может быть сколь угодно много, а определение лишь одно. Но ведь существуют `weak`-функции, которые могут иметь сколь угодно определений. Например, в этом случае:

```
_weak int foo()
{
    return 0;
}
int foo()
{
    return 1;
}
```

скомпилируются обе функции, но линковщик выбросит "слабую". В этом случае:

```
_weak int foo()
{
    return 0;
}
_weak int foo()
{
    return 1;
}
```

линковщик не сможет выбрать правильную функцию и выдаст ошибку. В этом случае:

```
_weak int foo()
{
    return 0;
}
```

всё в порядке, ошибок нет. Слабое связывание применяется, в основном, в низкоуровневом программировании при создании обработчиков прерываний. Обычно в библиотеках, работающих с ядром, создаются обработчики прерываний по умолчанию, и они определяются как `weak`. При этом программист может написать свой обработчик, который никак не будет конфликтовать с обработчиком по умолчанию.

---

UPD. Насчет стандарта не знаю, не читал (всё-таки [денег стоит](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/417798/3380)), но [в документации по gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) это есть.

> The weak attribute causes the declaration to be emitted as a weak symbol rather than a global. This is primarily useful in defining library functions which can be overridden in user code, though it can also be used with non-function declarations. Weak symbols are supported for ELF targets, and also for a.out targets when using the GNU assembler and linker.

Comment: Ну, хм, это какая-то компиляторо- и платформоспецифическая фича. В стандарте такого всё же нет.